# Is it possible to add values to tree nodes?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Is it possible to add text, and a value, to a tree node?

For example, a node may have the text `Desktop`, but the value is `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop`.

Comment: Is this a WPF, Winforms or Webforms Tree view control?

Comment: OK. In WPF, Winforms or Webforms?

Comment: I assume this is Windows Forms TreeView control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may to use Tag property for storing values:

```
TreeNode node = new Node();
node.Tag = "value";
```

Advantage is that you can assign to Tag any object you want not just integer or string value.

Then you can use Tag as follow:

```
var value = node.Tag as YourObjectType;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I only need to use a single string value. I was just about to write a Dictionary<String, String>, and go through the hassle of checking if the boxes are checked and getting the values from the Dictionary. Saved me a little time.

Comment: @James Jeffery : Out of curiosity what was wrong with my answer posted first?

Comment: @Ian nothing bud, sash provided a bit more info, but your information was just the same. If I could tick both boxes I would. When I refreshed the page there were 2 answers. Nothing personal :)

Comment: @James. Ok fair enough. Newest normally get shoved to the top automatically :(

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old post, but just in case anyone still wants the solution.

```
myTreeView.Nodes.Add("Key", "Text");
```

And you can access like

```
var key = myTreeView.SelectedNode.Name;
var text = myTreeView.SelectedNode.Text;
```

Answer (score 2):

A TreeNode has a [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag.aspx) property. You can set that to any object you like and can use as your underlying value, while the normal text of the node is displayed in the tree.

E.g.

```
TreeNode node = new TreeNode("Desktop") { Tag = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop" };
```